# Kubernetes on Mesos

Tags: docker, containers, mesos, kubernetes

I Have the following setup in mind:
Kubernetes on Mesos (based on the kubernetes-mesos project) within a /16 network.
Each pod will have its own IP and I believe this will avail 64 000 pods.
The idea is to provide isolation for each app i.e. Each app gets its own mysql within the same pod - the app accesses mysql on localhost(within the pod).
If an additional service were needed, I'd use kubernetes rolling updates to add the service's container to the pod, the app will be able to access this new service on localhost as well.
Each application needs as much isolation as possible.

1. Are there any defects to such an implementation?
2. Do I have to use weave?

   - There's an option to specify the service-ip-range while running the kubernetes-mesos install.
3. One hole is how do I scale a service, is this really viable?
4. Is there a better way to do this? i.e. Offering isolated services

Thanks.
PS//I'm obviously a noobie at this and I'm trying to get the best possible setup running.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sort of design will work for small applications, but you're right that it'll be tough to scale up if you suddenly want two have a couple instances of a service hit the same mysql backend.

You may want to look into putting each service into a separate namespace. Then a service's DNS lookups will be scoped to its own namespace by default so that it won't find other services' resources unless it's explicitly looking for them. This would let you put mysql (and any other dependencies) in a separate pod so that the frontend could be scaled independently.

Comment: This is exactly right for me, namespaces allow me to regulate resources i.e. cpu, ram, however according to Stefan Schimanski Kubernetes namespaces are only logical and the pods can still find each other over eg. dns One way of overcoming this is by using authorization and authentication plugins, is there perhaps a better way to achieve full separation of pod groups? Other than creating overlay networks?

Answer (score 3):

A common misconception is that a Pod should manage a vertical, multi-tier stack: for example a web tier + DB tier together.

It's interesting to read the [Kubernetes design intent of Pods](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/kubernetes/blob/master/docs/user-guide/pods.md#uses-of-pods): they're for collecting 'helper' processes rather than composing a vertical stack.

To answer your questions, I'd recommend:

- Define a Pod template for the web tier only. This can be scaled to any size required, using a replication controller (questions #1 and #3).
- Define another Pod for MySQL.
- Use the [Service abstraction](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/kubernetes/blob/master/docs/user-guide/services.md) to locate these components.

Comment: The downside is that vanilla MySQL doesn't scale very well and isn't particularly cloud-native. What you'll probably want to do for production is to deploy an HA mysql wrapper like [Galera](http://galeracluster.com/products/). I don't know of anyone that's done that in Kubernetes. But if you can't figure it out you can always host it externally and use a headless service to let k8s pods find it.

Comment: Thank you, the best solution seems to be a separate pod for the app container, a separate pod for each service and put it all in a namespace, this way there's some level of separation and each component can be scaled according to demand

Comment: One  thing that bothers me though, is it "right" to create a service for an application pod? E.g. I have a Python/Flask app in this pod and I define a service for it? I've sen this on tutum's wordpress tutorial

Comment: It's perfectly reasonable to create a k8s service to give any set of replicated pods a single shared "static" IP. Anything you would load balance you should probably give a k8s service.